# Java parallel volatile i++

Tags: java, multithreading, increment, runnable, race-condition

I have a global variable

```
volatile i = 0;
```

and two threads. Each does the following:

```
i++;
System.out.print(i);
```

I receive the following combinations. 12, 21 and 22.

<s>I understand why I don't get 11 (volatile disallows the caching of i) and</s> I also understand 12 and 22.

What I don't understand is how it is possible to get 21?

The only possible way how you can get this combination is that the thread that prints later had to be the first to increment `i` from 0 to 1 and then cached `i==1`. Then the other thread incremented `i` from 1 to 2 and then printed 2. Then the first thread prints the cached `i==1`. But I thought that `volatile` disallow caching.

Edit: After running the code 10,000 times I got 11 once. Adding `volatile` to `i` does not change the possible combinations at all.

markspace is right: volatile forbids caching `i` but `i++` is not atomic. This means that `i` still gets sort of "cached" in a register during the incrementation.

```
r1 = i
//if i changes here r1 does not change
r1 = r1 + 1 
i = r1
```

This is the reason why 11 is still possible. 21 is caused because PrintStreams are not synchronized (see Karol Dowbecki's answer)

Comment: As I answered below, that isn't strictly true that "volatile disallows caching".  Because the read, increment and write are all separate operations that may happen in parallel, the value of `i` can effectively be cached.

Comment: @markspace I would say allow as long as happens before is respected. This can be done at cache-coherence level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `++` is not an atomic operation.  Despite `volatile` not allowing caching, it is permitted for the JVM to read, increment, and then write as separate operations.  Thus, the concept you are trying to implement just isn't workable.  You need to use `synchronized` for its mutex, or use something like `AtomicInteger` which does provide an atomic increment operation.

Answer (score 6):

Your code does not guarantee which thread will call [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) first.

The increments and reads for `i` happened in order due to `volatile` keyword but prints didn't.

Comment: Good edit.  Another point of contention is that you are not addressing the race conditions inherent with the volatile ++.  See @markspace's answer.  You might get 1 2 3 3 4 4 5...

Answer (score 1):

> The only possible way...is that the thread that prints later had to be the first to increment i from 0 to 1 and then cached i==1...

You are forgetting about what `System.out.print(i);` does:  That statement calls the `System.out` object's `print(...)` method with whatever *value* was stored in `i` at the moment when the call was started.

So here's one scenario that could happen:

```
Thread A
increments i  (i now equals 1)
Starts to call `print(1)`  //Notice! that's the digit 1, not the letter i.
gets bogged down somewhere deep in the guts...

          Thread B
          increments i (i=2)
          Calls `print(2)`
          Gets lucky, and the call runs to completion.

Thread A
finishes its `print(1)` call.
```

Neither thread is *caching* the `i` variable.  But, the `System.out.print(...)` function doesn't know anything about your `volatile int i`.  It only knows about the *value* (1 or 2) that was passed to it.